# How to generate a PDF with auto flow

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrobat

I wrote a web app for generating PDF by filling data into a pre-saved PDF template, template edited by acrobat, with some text-fields. But the context of those text-fields seems in a different layer and cannot affect other existing words in template.

... But I want it affect the existing words and make them flow base on how many data fill into the text-fields.

The solution maybe use program to generate a whole PDF instead of using template. But the template changes really often in my case, I don't want waste a lot of time to adjust the position and format by coding...

Do anyone know how to use text-field with auto flow in a PDF template? just like a Word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF doesn't work like that.  You need to generate the whole PDF.

#### Ah... but from what?

There are quite a few HTML->PDF converters out there.  You could fill in your template HTML, and convert it that way.

You could develop your own input format (for your template), and write an app that reads it and builds a PDF.

The later is similar enough to HTML->PDF, that unless you can't find a converter that handles some PDF feature or other you need, I'd just go that route.  There are LOTS of html->pdf apps out there.  You can search SO, google, whatever.  Lots.